# How do I Display Select Pixels of an Image Using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, graphics

I'm trying to define pixels of an image based on their color code, and display them on command. I've been researching this and can't seem to find information on the subject, I've mostly been pointed towards "Animations" and "Core Image Filters" which isn't quite what I'm looking for. Any information on the subject is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jjxtra/DRColorPicker

try this sample code of a color picker. one of the views is a plane of continuous colors and is probably what you want. apple has good source code and the swift book is great for avoiding bad questions. you have to watch it as a beginer.too many simple questions on this site and they will block you from asking more.